# Using Session is giving error

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have an `aspx` page where I am calling a function like below

```
public static string FunFillEmp(object[] args)
        {

            string StrPriReturn = "";
            DataAccessLayer ObjPriDt = new DataAccessLayer();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = ObjPriDt.ExecuteDataTable("select mkey,Emp_Name,emp_card_no from emp_mst where "+
                                            "department_mkey='" + args[0].ToString() + "' and status in ('A','S') and hub_mkey IN  " +
                                            "(select hub_mkey from emp_mst e,user_mst u where e.mkey=u.employee_mkey and e.STATUS IN ('A','S')   "+
                                            "and u.mkey='" + Session["UserId"].ToString().Trim() + "') " +
                                             "order by 2");
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int IntpriI = 0; IntpriI < dt.Rows.Count; IntpriI++)
                {
                    StrPriReturn += dt.Rows[IntpriI][0].ToString() + "~" + dt.Rows[IntpriI][1].ToString() + "~" + dt.Rows[IntpriI][2].ToString() + "|";
                }
            }
            return StrPriReturn;
        }
```

But Using `Session` is giving me error as

> an object reference required for nonstatic field

So how would I use Session here?

Comment: @N K Have you assigned any value to `Session`. If so can we see it?

Comment: @DheerajPatnaik: I haven't assigned any value to `Session`

Comment: @N K that's why it is throwing an error.You are trying to retrieve a value from `null`

Comment: @DheerajPatnaik: that's not the issue. Any way I got the solution from below answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"]` since you're accessing it inside a `static` method.

And yes, you'll need to handle the scenario when you do not assign anything into the Session.

Comment: Thanks user1645120, it worked perfectly fine with what I was wanted

Answer (score 0):

Your Session is not assigned, you need to handle that case:

```
string UserId = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"] == null ? null : HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"].ToString().Trim();

if(UserId == null)
{
    // do something
}

dt = ObjPriDt.ExecuteDataTable("select mkey,Emp_Name,emp_card_no from emp_mst where " +
                                "department_mkey='" + args[0].ToString() + "' and status in ('A','S') and hub_mkey IN  " +
                                "(select hub_mkey from emp_mst e,user_mst u where e.mkey=u.employee_mkey and e.STATUS IN ('A','S')   " +
                                "and u.mkey='" + UserId + "') " +
                                    "order by 2");
```